# How to print opentracing 'uber-trace-id' via logback.xml in log files?

Tags: spring-boot, microservices, opentracing, jaeger

I am using spring-boot with open-tracing enabled for microservices developement. 
I would like to print the 'uber-trace-id' header value in my log file. I understand that I can load that value into MDC context and print it in log file. I am thinking of implementing a 'HandlerInterceptor' and intercept each request to look for 'uber-trace-id' header and load its value to MDC context so that I can print in log file. Is it the right method? Anyother better possible approach is there ?